# Finding the MLE of $P(x\leq y)$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I have a similar question to the one posted here: [Maximum likelihood estimator of $P(X < y)$ for fixed $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631261/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-px-y-for-fixed-y). However, the answer here seems quite vague and I can't seem to get any conclusions from it.

Could someone explain this better or post a solution? thanks

Comment: One approach is use the chain rule.  That is, to maximize likelihood $f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)$ with respect to $P(X_i<y)$ (for some fixed $y$ and scalar $\theta$), and assuming an interior solution where the first order condition is met, you would solve $0=\partial_{P(X_i<y)} f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=\frac{\partial_{\theta} f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)}{\partial_\theta P(X_i<y)}$

Comment: Then you plug whatever $\hat\theta$ you get from the first order condition into $P(X_i<y)$ to get an MLE for $P(X_i<y)$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I'm still confused about this, why do we suddenly take the derivative of $f$ with respect to $P(X\leq y)$? Could you maybe post a solution with some more details?

Comment: Well let me ask you, how would would typically find an MLE for $\theta$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio take the likelihood function (the product of n densities) and differentiate it with respect to the parameters of the model. Then it's just basic calculus. I'm just confused here because I don't know how to find the likelihood function where we can differentiate to $P(X \leq y)$.

Comment: @ Geigercounter, Right so you now you have to differentiate likelihood with respect to $P(X\leq y),$ which is in turn a function of the parameter $\theta$.  What I am saying is use the chain rule to do so, which tells us $\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}=\frac{df(x)/dx}{dg(x)/dx}$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I still don't seem to get it.... If I apply your strategy to this specific problem I get $$\left( \frac{n}{\theta+1} + \sum^n_{i=1}\ln x_i \right) \frac{1}{Z\ln y} = 0$$ which doesn't give me an estimator for $Z$.

Comment: The accepted answer to this problem baffles me as well, specifically where is says "that is to find the maximum likelihood estimator for the parameter $\theta$ and replace it where it is asked." Is this really appropriate to find the MLE of $\mathbb{P}(X<y)$?

Comment: @MatthewH. Exactly! I think it should be quite straightforward but that post made me totally confused... Could you maybe post a correct answer over there?

Comment: Consider $X_1,...,X_n \sim f$ and put $A_i=1$ if $X_i<y$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $A=A_1+\dots + A_n \sim \text{Binomial}\left(y^{\theta+1},n\right)$ counts the number of data values less than $y$. If you *observe* exactly $a$ data points that are less than $y$, then $$\mathbb{P}(A=a|\theta)= {n \choose a}\left(y^{\theta+1}\right)^a\left(1-y^{\theta+1}\right)^{n-a}$$ The above is maximized when $\mathbb{P}(X<y)=y^{\theta+1}=\frac{a}{n}$ which makes intuitive sense to me.

Comment: @MatthewH. I'm not with you on that one, why don't you calculate it like Golden_ratio proposed?

Comment: @Geigercounter Convince yourself that finding the MLE of $\mathbb{P}(X<y)$ is really no different than finding the MLE of the unknown probability $p$ that a coin lands on heads after a single coin flip. A very natural way to estimate $\mathbb{P}(X<y)$ is to simply count the number of observations less than $y$ (which I call $a$) and then divide by the total number of observations, $n$.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio could you post your solution? thanks

Comment: posted-lmk if you agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the example in your link, suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid, each with density $$f_X(x;\theta)=(1+\theta)x^\theta,\quad x\in [0,1].$$

We have likelihood $$L(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=\Pi_i f_X(x_i;\theta)=(1+\theta)^n\Pi_ix_i^\theta.$$

We also have $G(y;\theta)\equiv P(X_i\leq y)=y^{1+\theta }$ for fixed $y\in(0,1)$. We wish to find an MLE for $G(y;\theta).$

Now if the solution is an interior one where the first order condition is met, then you could appeal to the chain rule to obtain first order condition with respect to $G(y;\theta)$:

$$0=\partial_{G(y;\theta)} \log L(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=\frac{\partial_{\theta} \log L(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)}{\partial_{\theta} G(y;\theta)}.$$

Note $G(y;\theta)$ is monotonically strictly decreasing in $\theta.$ So the FOC here is the same as FOC for an MLE for $\theta$:

$$0=\partial_{\theta} \log L(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)\implies \hat\theta =-\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\log x_i}+1\right),$$

giving an MLE for $G(y;\theta)$ of $G(y;\hat\theta)$.

Comment: Indeed that's what I was able to obtain for the MLE of $\theta$, but I don't get why this is also a MLE for $P(X \leq y)$?

Comment: The first order condition is the same; the claim is that the MLE for $G(y,\theta)$ is $G(y;\hat\theta)$ as your link mentions.  Think about it this way; you know how to find an  MLE for $\theta$. Now $G(y;\theta)$ is strictly monotonic in $\theta$, i.e. there is a one-to-one map between the values $\theta$ can take on and the values $G(y;\theta)$ can take on. So when $G(y;\theta)$ takes on the value $G(y;\hat \theta)$, this implies $\theta$ takes on the value $\hat \theta$, which is exactly what maximizes the likelihood. Make sense?